# How can I save user data on user's local device in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

So I am building an app with a ListView of let's say some words. I have also created a screen where the user can save words when clicking of "favorite word".
How can I save that info for every user so that when they log in again they have the same information saved?
The app does not have an auth method yet. Is it necessary for this?

Comment: you have a lot of choices, please be more specific, do you want the app to work offline only? do you have a lot of data with complex relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store data locally on the user device you do not need to implement any auth functionality.

To persist data locally on a device you can use any of the following [Sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite), [Moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter), [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), [GetX Storage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage)

I find GetX Storage the easiest way to store data that has no relationships.

This is a tutorial on shared preferences:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szOllHT1S7Y

This is also a tutorial for GetX Storage:
https://youtu.be/ttQtlX_Q0eU?t=430